# create and read tar.bz2 files in perl

Tags: perl, compression, tar

I have been trying to use

```
system("tar -jcvf archive_name.tar.bz2 $my_file")
```

but I get an error

> archive_name.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory 
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now 
>   tar: Child returned status 2

Is it not possible to create .tar.bz2 using this method in perl? I would prefer not to use a module but will if it is absolutely necessary

Comment: Which is it? `archive_name.tar.bz2` or `t.tar.bz2`?

Comment: What about `tar cf - my_file | bzip2 > archive_name.tar.bz2`?

Comment: are you suggesting putting all of that inside a system() statement? I can try that.

*I edited my mistake in pasting the error message

Comment: Thank you tar cf - my_file | bzip2 > archive_name.tar.bz2 worked! Do you know why that would work and my way wouldn't?

Comment: I can speculate. Your version of `tar` doesn't support the `-j` option? Your version of `tar` was compiled against a different and incompatible bzip2 library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not doing it *in Perl*. You're spawning a separate process that runs the command.

If you want to do this *in Perl*, you would need to use the [Archive::Tar](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html) module and possibly [IO::Compress::Bzip2](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Compress/Bzip2.html) module too.

First thing is to see if you can run this command straight from the command line:

```
$ tar -jcvf archive_name.tar.bz2 $my_file
```

If you can't run the tar command from the command line, it's highly unlikely to be able to run it from inside Perl using the `system` command.

The way you ran the command, with the command and all of the arguments in a single strung,  causes Perl to run the command from a shell (usually `/bin/sh`). If you run the command with the arguments in a list, Perl will run the command directly without a shell:

```
my $error = system qw( tar -jcvf archive_name.tar.bz2 $my_file );
```

Always check the output of the system command and also the value of `$?`. The [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command documentation has more information about processing errors.