# Create ZIP file in perl without using CPAN modules

Tags: perl, zip

I need to create a zip file in perl.enter code here
e.g. Exisiting file name is 2.csv I want a script to make it 2.zip
I have tried

```
my $file = 'dispatch_report_seg_flo.csv' ;
# Retrieve the namme of the file to archive.
print("Name the file to archive: ");

# Confirm the file exists, if not exit the program.
(-e $file) or die("Cannot find file `$file_nm`.\n");

# Zip the file.
print("Trying file name '$file.zip'");
system("zip 'dispatch.zip' '$file'");
my $file1 = 'dispatch.zip';
```

Comment: can u tell me what are all the modules you are having?

Comment: Why is the code I post to SO ok, but not the code I post to CPAN?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question! What problem are you having? What error did you get?

Answer (score 6):

That should have worked unless the file name has single quotes in them. Here are two better ways:

1. `system($EXECUTABLE, @ARGS)`, which doesn't needlessly spawn a shell.

   ```
   system("zip", "dispatch.zip", $file);
   ```
2. `system($SHELL_COMMAND)`, which requires the creation of a shell command.

   ```
   # A poor substitute for String::ShellQuote's shell_quote
   sub shell_quote {
       my @s = @_;
       for (@s) { s/'/'\\''/g; $_ = "'$_'"; }
       return join(' ', @s);
   }

   system(shell_quote("zip", "dispatch.zip", $file));
   ```

   Obviously, the first solution is better, but you might want to use this solution if you wanted to do some kind of shell redirection.

   ```
   system(shell_quote("zip", "dispatch.zip", $file) . ' >/dev/null');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

this link may help you...[create and read tar.bz2 files in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613737/create-and-read-tar-bz2-files-in-perl)
if you wan to zip file using perl modules then use

```
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);

  zip [ glob("*.xls") ] => "test_zip.zip"
    or die "some problem: $ZipError" ;
```

add those lines into use script if you want

Answer (score -1):

Remove the ' characters:

```
system("zip dispatch.zip $file");
```

Comment: How does that help? Before your change, it only failed for files with single quotes in their name. After your change, it fails for a whole lot more, including files with spaces in their name.

Comment: didn't you see the name of the file at the first line? there aren't space blanks

Comment: So you're saying one should look beyond the higher-than-necessary [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29), making your answer merely useless?

Comment: I said you have done some serious over-engineering